# How to alternate queries from drop down menu in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, drop-down-menu

Hello Help Community,

I am trying to find a way to alternate queries from drop down menus. The idea is to be able to move between a list of queries and not have to rewrite the query when I want to use it again. I saw this done by writing the select statement in a drop down and referencing the cell containing the select statement in the query like this:

=QUERY(range, "" """"""&cell&"""""" "")

However, I cannot get this method to work. I can manipulate the same query using cell references and drop down menus but I would like to do more if it is possible.

Any idea how this could be achieved would be appreciated.

Regards, Andrew H"

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

example:

```
=QUERY(A2:D5, "where A = '"&B8&"'", 1)
```

[image]

if dropdown contains numbers use:

```
=QUERY(A2:D5, "where A = "&B8, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you playerO. I ended up recorded macros of a replacing the = sign in the queries and running them then assigned the script to buttons. This works to move through different queries with only minor clumsiness in that I have to select a cell in the same column I recorded the macro or I get a ref error. The macros also jump one cell down from the cell I have selected. I have the queries referenced to drop down cells to filter. Now if only I could find a way to insert the buttons in cells and with dependent drop downs. I would have more space.